# How to determine if Mnemonic/KeyCombination for a control is triggered?

Tags: java, javafx

I'd like to know how can I determine if the KeyCombination (constructed via Mnemonic) for a control is triggered. Or for simplicity's sake, a handler method for Mnemonics?

Basically, I'm working with a custom control which extends from [`Labeled`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html) and from its `Behavior` class, I want to perform some extra actions when the assigned Mnemonic is triggered.

---

## EDIT

So after a little bit digging, I came up with an idea to simply listen to a `KeyEvent` from the `Scene` (but take note that this is JUST AN IDEA. Either way, I'll figure out the rest later on). Here's how:

```
public CustomLabeledBehavior(CustomLabeled control) {
  super(control, ...);

  /* IMPORTANT PART */
  // Assume that mnemonicParsing is set to true
  TextBinding tb = new TextBinding(control.getText());
  KeyCombination kc = tb.getMnemonicKeyCombination();

  control.getScene().addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
    if (kc.match(e)) {
      System.out.println("MATCHED!");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Do you have any relevant code? Please, edit your question if so.

Comment: @Nikolas Additional info: basically, there's a handler method for mouse-related events and we can also `Bind` keyboard shortcuts. But I don't have any idea how to work with Mnemonics, so I can't present a code right now. P.S I never tried anything yet.

Comment: Are you saying you want different behavior depending on if your `CustomLabeled` was clicked via mouse or was "clicked" via a key binding?

Comment: @Slaw I'm looking for a way to determine if the `KeyCombination` that is set via Mnemonic was triggered. OR simply, a handler method (like `mousePressed` for mouse event).

Comment: Take a look at [`Scene.addMnemonic(Mnemonic)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#addMnemonic(javafx.scene.input.Mnemonic)), [`Scene.removeMnemonic(Mnemonic)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#removeMnemonic(javafx.scene.input.Mnemonic)), and [`Scene.getMnemonics()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#getMnemonics()). This method may also be useful: [`Scene.getAccelerators()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#getAccelerators()).

Comment: @Slaw Thank you for providing reference. I appreciate it so much.

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE

To make this answer more useful than it used to be, I'll show you the usage of the method I'm currently using to determine if the `KeyCombination` is triggered. So I'll try to explain every single detail if I can.

We are only focusing on adding a `Mnemonic`, using the `MnemonicParsing` property of a custom control. And we will call this custom control as `CustomLabeled` since based on the question, it extends from the `Labeled` class, hence the name is based to it. Then we will work things inside its `Skin` class called, `CustomLabeledSkin`.

**#1** Initializing the control:

```
<!-- Assuming that this FXML is already set and is attached to a Scene -->
<CustomLabeled text="_Hello World!" mnemonicParsing="true"/>
```

**#2** Setting up our `MnemonicHandler`:

```
/* These two variables are initialized from the Constructor. */
private KeyCombination kb; // The combination of keys basically, ALT + Shortcut key
private String shortcut; // The shortcut key itself basically, a Letter key

private boolean altDown = false; // Indicator if the user press ALT key

/**
 * This handler is a convenience variable to easily attach
 * and detach to the Scene's event handlers. This is the
 * whole idea to determine whether the KeyCombination is
 * triggered.
 */
private EventHandler<KeyEvent> mnemonicHandler = new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
    // The KeyCombination, basically, the ALT + Shortcut key.
    if (kb.match(event) {
      // TODO: Execute command here.
      event.consume(); // Prevent from further propagation.
      return; // Make sure that the rest won't be executed.
    }
    // While these two functions are for separate event.
    // Example, pressing ALT first before the Shortcut key.
    if (event.isAltDown()) altDown = !altDown;
    if (altDown && event.getCode() == KeyCode.getKeyCode(shortcut)) {
      // TODO: Execute command here.
      event.consume();
    }
  }
}
```

**#3** Initialize our Skin class:

```
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public CustomLabeledSkin(CustomLabeled control) {
  // Since this is just an example/testing, we will only assume
  // that MnemonicParsing is enabled and a valid Mnemonic is
  // registered. So if you want to validate a mnemonic, you
  // might want to do it here.
  TextBinding tb = new TextBinding(control.getText());
  kc = tb.getMnemonicKeyCombination();
  shortcut = tb.getMnemonic();

  // Then we can just filter for a KEY_PRESS from the Scene, then
  // everything else will be handled by our MnemonicHandler.
  control.getScene().addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, mnemonicHandler);
}
```

> **NOTE:** The `TextBinding` class is not part of the public API, it is used by the `Labeled` node to handle Mnemonics.

Further more, you can create a method to detach the `MnemonicHandler` if there's no currently Mnemonics assigned (E.g previously there's a mnemonic, then code was changed...).

Comment: beware: in fx18 `TextBinding` will be renamed to `MnemonicInfo` - see https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/pull/678